# PowerShell: Make an Installation Process Silent

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

I have a script that calls an application from Microsoft's Company Portal and automatically installs it. This launches Company Portal, potentially disrupting end user workflow. Is there any way to make this process run in the background? I tried to add an Argument List, but the process still launches Company portal. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$OutputFile = "$env:WINDIR\TEMP\PythoncpInstall.log"
$Process = "companyportal:ApplicationId=e60a5520-dc39-4156-9223-825264cd5145"
$ProcessArgs = " /s -Wait -NoNewWindow"

##########ERROR LOGGING#####
Function Set-WriteToLog ($Write1)
{
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)`t-`t$Write1"
}
#########START OF SCRIPT BODY#############
Start-Transcript -Path $OutputFile
start-process $Process -ArgumentList $ProcessArgs
sleep 10
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{i}")

Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the application and its installer, I'm not sure how if what I will suggest will work.  Please share this information when you can.

What *might* help you is using `Start-Process` with `-RedirectStandardInput` and `-WindowStyle`.

`-RedirectStandardInput` will allow you to provide a text file that will be passed to standard input.  This *might* let you provide input, depending on how the installer is implemented.

`-WindowStyle` would allow you to launch the process minimized or hidden.

Unfortunately, the way your code is currently written relies on SendKeys, which would in turn rely on the window being visible and focused.

Please let me know what installer you're using (if it's external), and I might be able to provide more help.

Comment: I am attempting to install python version 3.10 from company portal. Python 3.10 i available for download with an .exe, not an .msi. This application has been packaged internally and made available in Company portal for users to install, but I want to install it in the background without disruption. Thanks for the help.